# How to prevent from DataAnnotations Attributes being deleted in DataBase First Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, edmx, database-first

I have my asp.net mvc 3 application with entity framework and i used the Database First model to set it up.

My Steps below:
 1. Genarated a database with tables
 2. Created ADO.NET Entity Data Model file (.edmx) and imported the tables
 3. inside the design i added a Code Generation item and used ADO.NET DbContext Generator
 4. a Model1.tt holder as been made with all of the tables Models

I have edited the models and updated them with DataAnnotations Attributes (just for the example a well known one)

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Now when im making changes to the database and updating it to the edmx file all the models will be overwritten and the DataAnnotations Attributes will disapear.

my question:
how can i use database first model and still edit the models for speciific validation like im free to do with code first model?
(please no third party tools solution)
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use buddy classes. See my dated but still useful article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: This link helped me a lot hope it will do the same for someone else http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation

Answer (score 1):

[Use ViewModels in your Views](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/). This will decouple your EF entities from your UI logic.